# exclude particular posts in archive.php

Tags: posts

My archive file contains..

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

But i want to exclude few posts with their ids, how can i do that ?

Important! But those excluded posts should display in the Google search as normal, i don't want to loss them in the search engines.  Just i want to hide in my site only.

Thank you friends.

Comment: You need to use filter `pre_get_posts`. Check this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can exclude posts from archive pages with thee help of [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Exclude_Single_Posts_by_I.D_From_Home_Page) action. Usually `pre_get_posts` is used to modify main query, so it's best solution for your problem.

```
function my_custom_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    if ( $query->is_archive() ) {
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 7, 11, 21 ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_custom_get_posts', 1 );
```

Please notice `7, 11, 21` in above code, these are the post IDs we are excluding from archive pages. You can specify as many comma separated post IDs as you want.

Yes, it will not prevent Google to index them.

Comment: Thank you Robert, can you help how to use this function, i mean where can i put this function ? in functions.php or directly in archive.php  and can i remove first 'if' condition, seems its not necessary.

Comment: In `functions.php`. NO, do not remove `if-else` conditions otherwise these posts will not display anywhere on blog. These conditions are making sure that posts do not display in archive pages only.

Comment: Thanks a lot yar, its working great.  I mean do we need to use this... if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )      return; ?  please don't mind, i am fresh to wordpress that's why i am asking.

Comment: With that we are skipping the check for admin wordpress query and main wordpress query. So our function should not interfere with them. But it should not affect these, so you can test it by removing.

Comment: @Robert hue Link to the source of the code please.